# rails Group Strings inside String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I have an array looks like this

```
a = ["red apple juice", "red mango juice", "red berry juice" "red fish juice", 
      black berry juice, black potato juice, 
      yellow bananen juice, yellow ananas juice, yellow onion juice,
```

and i would like to have

```
{red => 4, black => 2, yellow => 3}
```

Comment: Do you want to count the first word (which happens to be a color in this example) or do you want to count the names of the color in the hash? What if the color is at a different place in the string? What if there is no color or another color (blue) in the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#tally`](https://medium.com/@baweaver/ruby-2-7-enumerable-tally-a706a5fb11ea):

```
a = [ 
      "red apple juice", 
      "red mango juice", 
      "red berry juice",
      "red fish juice", 
      "black berry juice", 
      "black potato juice", 
      "yellow bananen juice", 
      "yellow ananas juice",  
      "yellow onion juice"
]

a.map {|s| s.split.first.to_sym }.tally # => {:red=>3, :black=>2, :yellow=>3}
```

Comment: TIL about `.tally` :-)

Comment: u are my savior